# codebuild stage fails with "Specified key does not exist error"" in AWS CDK 2.63.2

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have the following CDK code that creates a CloudFormation stack with an S3 bucket, codecommit and codepipeline.

```
    assets = s3d.BucketDeployment(
    self,
    "codeassets",
    destination_bucket=pipeline_bucket,
    role=reader_role,
    cache_control=[
s3d.CacheControl.from_string(
    "max-age=0,no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate"
)
    ],
    memory_limit=2048,
    sources=[s3d.Source.asset(assetspath)],
)


q = codecommit.CfnRepository(
    scope=self,
    code={
        "branch_name": "main",
        "s3": {"bucket": pipeline_bucket.bucket_name, "key": "code.zip"},
    },
    id="coderepo",
    repository_name=pipeline.repo,
)
q.node.add_dependency(assets)

p = codepipeline.Pipeline(
    scope=self,
    id=f"{pipeline.name}",
    pipeline_name=f"{pipeline.name}",
    restart_execution_on_update=True,
    artifact_bucket=pipeline_bucket,
)
p.node.add_dependency(q)
```

Even though the dependencies are added correctly, the CodePipeline stages are failing with the following error every time after the CloudFormation stack is updated.

```
[Container] 2023/10/17 10:01:14 Waiting for agent ping
[Container] 2023/10/17 10:01:26 Waiting for DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist.

status code: 404, request id: 3Z90D1YGC46ZQTXZ, host id: sgsg+kiejfbfbhj+sgrf+/sg= for primary source and source version arn:aws:s3:::pipeline-name-us-east-1-63bd58d0/pipeline-name/Artifact_S/SJKGDS
```

Provided below is one of the stage where the error pops up after the stack update.

## Source stage

```
    p.add_stage(
        stage_name="Source",
        actions=[
            codepipeline_actions.CodeCommitSourceAction(
                action_name="CodeCommit",
                branch="main",
                output=source_artifact,
                trigger=codepipeline_actions.CodeCommitTrigger.EVENTS,
                repository=codecommit.Repository.from_repository_name(
                    self, "source_glue_repo", repository_name=pipeline.repo
                ),
            )
        ],
    )

p.add_stage(
    stage_name="UnitTests",
    actions=[
        codepipeline_actions.CodeBuildAction(
            action_name="UnitTests",
            input=source_artifact,
            project=build_project_run_tests,
            outputs=[build_artifact_run_tests],
        )
    ],
)

    build_artifact_run_tests = codepipeline.Artifact()
```

When I check the S3, I cannot even find the folder "pipeline-name/Artifact_S/"

But when I click on the "Release Change" button on the right top of the pipeline page in AWS console, those artifacts folders are created and pipeline executions are successful.

How do I ensure the Source Output Artifacts are in S3 before CodePipeline stage UnitTests uses it as input artifact??

Comment: Your pipeline doesn't have any sources. What do you expect to happen in the pipeline?

Comment: Yes, I have a source which is codecommit and the pipeline is triggered upon every events to codecommit repo....

"codepipeline_actions.CodeCommitTrigger.EVENTS"  ...


There are a few stages in the pipeline and at the time of creation, everything works fine....

But, when we try to update the stack, it cannot access the objects in the s3. It is trying to access the objects (artifacts) before it is created/copied to s3.

Comment: Add the code that defines the stage that has the problem.

Comment: One of the stages where the error occurs is added to the question. But there are other stages too that are looking for the missing artifacts folder in S3.

When I check the S3, I cannot even find the folder "pipeline-name/Artifact_S/"

But when I trigger the pipeline manually using the "Release Change" button on the right top of the pipeline page in the AWS console, those artifacts folders are created and pipeline executions are successful.

How do I ensure the Source Output Artifacts are in S3 before the CodePipeline stage UnitTests uses it as input artifact??

Comment: The stage you added consumes `source_artifact` as its source, you'll need to include the stage/action that produces that artifact.

Comment: Oops! sorry.. you mean the source stage. That is now added. Please check.

Comment: The code seems to be in the wrong order, can you post the complete code that would reproduce the error?

Comment: Order is now corrected in the question. The stack creation actually works fine and the pipeline is executed successfully when it is created. The issue occurs when we try to update the stack.

Comment: Update it how? What is the update?

Comment: The normal CDK stack update using Python.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255716/discussion-between-gshpychka-and-ashfaq).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asset you are uploading to create the CodeCommit repo overwrites the repository files on every update.

You cannot change the content of the CodeCommit repo after it's created, so any subsequent changes to the `code` prop are ignored. Instead, whenever your code asset changes, your `BucketDeployment` construct removes any existing files in the bucket and replaces them with your asset. Set `prune` to false to disable this behavior.

Comment: Excellent, I see that in the documentation later. Your solution is the best approach.

Earlier, I was able to fix the issue by changing the artifact bucket setting to default, and thus CDK creates a dedicated bucket for artifacts. We were using a custom bucket before; "pipeline_bucket".

The root cause is that the artifacts folder was removed during the stack update, the executed stage cannot find the artifacts folder and cannot write to it. 

With a dedicated bucket, the artifacts are not removed during stack update, ensuring that all stages have access to the required artifacts.

Comment: And yes, I know the limitation with codecommit unable to update the contents of the repo with the stack update. I have written a separate function for that.

Comment: I see that the artifacts keep building up in the artifacts folder upon each execution. Do you know of any method with which we can delete the old artifacts that are not used anymore?

Comment: I think we can set 'retain_on_delete' to 'false'. I will try this.

Comment: Setting 'retain_on_delete' to 'false' doesn't work. Do you have any idea how to clean up old artifacts? ..... I have started working on a function to accomplish this. Any other easy method within CDK ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, to be honest. You are doing a lot of weird stuff and using CodeCommit in very unconventional ways, it seems, so you will probably need to open a new question and explain your flow in a lot more detail.

Comment: It is part of our application infrastructure.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not nearly enough information, you should explain the entire flow in a lot more detail in a new question

Comment: Sure, I will create one later. Working on a different topic right now.